# jquery cycle fade ie jpg images

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

Strange problem with jquery cycle plugin.
Works fine in every browser except IE8. image dissapear during transition.
i've seen that there could be problems with png images but my images are all jpg.
they are in html like: `<div><div><img src="img1"></div><div><img src="img2"></div></div>`
maybe it is because every image is inside div? i must have these divs so if this cause the problem is there any solution to it?

```
$('#mainFitScreenBack').cycle({
    timeout: 1000,
    speed:  1000,
    cleartypeNoBg:true,
    delay: -1000

});
```

Comment: hard to help without being able to inspect css. Best guess is no dimensions are set on images or their parent `div`. Post a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates the problem

Comment: charlietfl. thanks a million. indeed i had to set height and width for the images parent divs.  otherwise it was not working in IE8 even if images had proper dimensions set.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is somewhat redundant because you gave the answer, for IE you need to put specific measures.

That is to IE8 or earlier

```
width
height
```

If you want something flexible use v2.

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/basic.php